# react-form-validator-core what is the purpose of ref="form"

Tags: reactjs, validation

This is sample code taken from [react-form-validator-core](https://github.com/NewOldMax/react-form-validator-core). What is the purpose of the line `ref="form"`?

```
...
import { ValidatorForm } from 'react-form-validator-core';
...
render() {
    return (
        <ValidatorForm
            ref="form"
            onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
        >
            <TextValidator
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                name="email"
                value={email}
                validators={['required', 'isEmail']}
                errorMessages={['this field is required', 'email is not valid']}
            />
            <button type="submit">submit</button>
        </ValidatorForm>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's used to reference the `ValidatorForm` itself, allowing you to use functions such as `isFormValid`.

If you're looking to use it with react hooks (which is how I'm using it), you can do so by using the `useRef` hook.

Example:

```
const formRef = useRef(null);
...
<ValidatorForm ref={formRef}>
```

Comment: When using es-lint, I got “Using string literals in ref attributes is deprecated (react/no-string-refs)" error. So, instead of using **ref="the-form"**, I used the callback version like 
```ref={(r) => { this.form = r;}}``` creating a ref : **form: any = React.createRef()**. Is this the way to do it?